# Remote URL resolves when server is running locally but times out in production (heroku server)

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, server, axios

This url https://prodimage.images-bn.com/pimages/2940161410400_p0_v1_s550x406.jpg resolves locally but not in production (heroku server) (NodeJS express). I even tried routing through a proxy and again it resolves locally but times out on the server. I am just making a simple axios get request, I've also tried node-fetch and other libraries with no success. I even tried to switch my hosting provider to vercel and the behavior was the same. Very odd. I'm wondering if anyone has an explanation for why that is and if there is a work around that could be done to be able to fetch from that domain on my server.

Comment: I will also mention that other remote urls are fine it's just https://prodimage.images-bn.com that I'm having a problem with

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.